# pandas series elementwise muplication

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two pandas series a and b as follows:

```
a = pd.series([1, 2, 3])

b = pd.series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

What I want to get is a third pandas series as follows:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 10, 12], [21, 24, 27]]
```

I have tried the following operations:

```
a*b

np.array(a)*np.array(b)

np.multiple(a, b)

a.multiple(b)
```

However, I keep getting the same error as follows:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I wonder what's the right way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc), [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
c = np.array(b.values.tolist()) * a[:,np.newaxis])
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [21 24 27]]
```

Or:

```
c = np.array(b.values.tolist()) * a.values.reshape(len(a),-1)
print (c)
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [21 24 27]]
```

And then:

```
s3 = pd.Series(c.tolist())
print (s3)
0       [1, 2, 3]
1     [8, 10, 12]
2    [21, 24, 27]
dtype: object
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Can you help me understand why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I think you cannot use `a.mul(b)`, because in pandas is not implemented multiple in lists. Need create 2d numpy array with lists and then here the `newaxis` index operator inserts a new `axis` into a, making it a two-dimensional `3x1 array`.

Comment: Yea it makes sense! Thanks again!